# HP UFT screenshot image and compare

Tags: hp-uft, uft-api

I have a client that would like to run an automated test in an environment that captures full page screenshots of data on a web app and use those baseline images to compare against the same screens of a web app called from a VM for a subsequent test run. Can UFT do this, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [bitmap checkpoints](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/About_Checking_Bitmaps.htm) and see if this fits your needs.

If not you can use [`CaptureBitmap`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#CaptureBitmap) and do with the image whatever you want.